# Is it possible to observe a partially constructed object from another thread when the constructing thread does both writing and reading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, volatile

There is at least one question similar to this one, hovever I believe I have different constraints...
If I have a class with some number of fields and objects of this class are immutable, would it be theoretically possible (assuming weakest allowed memory model for the CLR) to observe a partially constructed object when the reference to the object is volatile and the thread creating the object is both writing and reading the reference (writes first)?

Correct me if I am wrong, but I understand the memory model such that if thread a constructs the object of class X and writes it's reference to some shared mutable volatile variable, then object construction cannot be
reordered after the volatile assignment. If thread b reads the reference and sees the new value, it is safe to assume that the object can be accessed, because it is also true that operations coming after the volatile read of reference cannot be reordered before it, so if thread2 sees the write it sees everything that came before. Is that true?

If so, does that change if the thread a first creates the object and then writes variable, and then reads the same variable again? we have (in thread a) object construction, then volatile write followed by volatile read of same variable (in program order) that ofc yields the correct value for thread a, but is it possible for thread b to somehow see the effects of the read before the write? I know that if release comes before acquire then they could legally be reordered, but not sure if I get the meaning right.

Comment: Showing an example code may help... So far it sounds like you are asking if you give another thread reference to partially constructed object will that other thread be able to use the reference - and the answer is "why do you expect it *not to happen?*"

Comment: I am generally asking about the things that could happen, even theoretically, under the CLR memory model. In this case it is a question about the allowed reorderings and their possible effects assuming weakest possible memory model compatible with the CLR. I can add some code tomorrow if it helps.

Comment: The question is: if thread1 constructs the object and writes it's reference to a volatile variable, then reads that reference from that variable, can another thread theoretically observe the read before the write happened, and does this mean that the second thread can in theory see a partially constructed object?

Comment: Interesting hypothesis.  Try it and see.  Create an experiment;  make measurements; compare your findings; post your code so that others may verify your observations.  Otherwise it seems to be just a thought experiment

Comment: This is a question about memory model. I am trying to improve my understanding of it by asking questions based on what I've heard. The problem is that these things are basically untestable. Can you predictably provoke race conditions? and in that case I would also need the cpu with a weak enough memory model to have the ability to trigger these races in cases I test. The only thing I can post would be example code showing what thread a and thread b is doing. Everything from that area seems to be a thought experiment related to carefully reading specifications (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) unless you have some hands on experience with that failing. I have heard about the dangers of using volatile including some evidence that in some cases it could theoretically cause partially constructed objects to be visible, but I don't have any info about when it would happen in case of the reference to this object being volatile and object being immutable after creation.